# MongoDB C#Driver resp. Linq: query for unique instances and using static AsQueryable Properties

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I am working on a rather large MongoDB database and am wondering if there is a more effective way to some queries. For example, I store lots of instances of `Game` in the db, where the `Game` class looks as follows:

```
public class Game{
    [BsonId]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    // ... some more properties

    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

where each game instance has a list of `Player`, which in turn has some properties, like `Name`.

In one view model I want to bind a `ComboBox` to the name of all players in the database - but recall that the same player might have played many games. I load them as follows:

```
private void LoadPlayersNames() {
    var _l = StaticMongo.GetGames.SelectMany(n => n.Players).Select(n => n.Name);
    PlayerNames = new ObservableCollection<string>(new HashSet<string>(_l));
}
```

And in the static class `StaticMongo` I have a static instance of the `MongoClient` and the `IMongoDatabase`, And I expose the `GetGames` property in `StaticMongo` as follows,

```
private readonly static IMongoDatabase _database;
public static IMongoQueryable<DetailedHand> GetGames { 
    get {
        return _database.GetCollection<Game>("Games").AsQueryable();
    } 
}
```

So to make this more conrete, following questions:

**1:** Is the way I get the unique player names (via `HashSet`) a good way or is there a better way to query for unique names in this context.
**2:** Does the static MongoDB instance, together with exposing the database collections AsQueryable have drawbacks?

I know the formulaion might be a bit opinion-based, yet I hope to get some alternative ways to do queries of this kind as this does not look to be the ideal way to me.

Comment: You could do a group on the players name and then only pull the name field (MongoDb server side call) . Or you could call Distinct() on the Select. if you want to load all that data from mongo.

Comment: Is that really faster? I mean grouping by name, then pulling the name only sounds like more work - although I ofc don't know how the linq method works in the background - instead of getting the data ungrouped, then construction a hashset on names - again not knowing how effective the hasthset constructor is.

Comment: Have you tried adding indexes??

Answer (score 0):

I feel you should use aggregation framework for finding unique names which is faster:

Pure mongo query would be:

```
db.games.aggregate( 
     { 
        "$unwind": "$players"   
     },   
     { 
        "$group": { 
            "_id": "$players.name",             
        }  
    }
 )
```

You can see [MongoDB Aggregation Framework Examples in C#](https://dzone.com/articles/mongodb-aggregation-framework) for converting my db query to C# usage.

**Update:**

Learning [aggregation in C#](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/aggregation/) for you. Believe me or not. But aggregation is faster than AsQueryable()

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("games");
var pipeline = collection.Aggregate()
    .Unwind(i => i.players)
    .Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$players.name" } });
```

Check if it is working.

Comment: The link you refer to uses the older version of the C# driver, which is fundamentally different ...

Comment: @EluciusFTW: I don't know C#. There must be new ways to use aggregation framework in C#. Mongo Query works fine for finding unique player names. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33130160/1045444

Comment: My question was specific to C#, and more specifically if it is a good idea to expose the collections as  `db.AsQueryable()` in a property of a static class and keep all database references within that class - so I'm not satisfied yet.

Comment: @EluciusFTW: Updated answer. Please check.